# Integrating Octopus Deploy and Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, octopus-deploy

I'm using an on premises version of CRM 2011, which I'm about to begin developing against.

We're using Octopus Deploy with some other sites.

It would be great if there was a way to import CRM Solutions using a powershell script or wcf service, rather then someone manually navigating to the site and go through the motions.(we have dev,test and prod environments)

I can't seem to find a non UI method of doing this online. Can anyone suggest a better solution then using the UI?

Comment: What is your experience with Octopus Deploy and CRM 2011. Would you recommend going down that path. We are considering the exact same move at my company.

Comment: It depends on the number of times you plan to deploy your solutions, and how many you have. It was useful to move changes from localhost into Dev, and ensure that they were captured within source control. Deployments to Test and Production were done manually by other teams. So Octopus was not has helpful as it would have been in a webapp, but better then nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can import solution programmatically using ImportSolutionRequest class. Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.importsolutionrequest.aspx)