# Is it possible to add and configure Dynamics CRM workflows with Powershell

Tags: powershell, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

Is it possible to deploy a managed solution to Microsoft Dyanamics CRM 2013/2015 with plugin assemblies via the UI, then use a PowerShell script to add workflows, and steps?

Comment: Been down that road before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13965635/integrating-octopus-deploy-and-dynamics-crm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: Yes - but you need to create .NET [cmdlets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878294%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which access CRM service which Powershell can run.

If you don't want to roll your own solution, this make be of use.
http://waelhamze.com/2013/08/20/automated-crm-deployments-powershell/